# awk command inside bash shell script loop

Tags: bash, awk, scripting, for

I have a `bash` script which is supposed to go through a series of files text file. I have written a `for` loop to do this job automatically for me but I am not getting any output files when the script runs.

I have attempted various single line commands that I have found online, but with no luck. I am looking to break these large files by "year". Any suggestions?

```
#!/usr/awk -f
        for i in *yyyymm.txt
        do
#       {FS = "," }
        awk -F "," 'BEGIN '$1 == 2002'END{ print $0 }' $i > "$i"-2002.dat
        gawk '$ 1==2002 { print $0 }' "$i" > "$i"-2002.dat
        awk '/2002/' "$i" > "$i"-2002.dat
```

Comment: That was a just the beginning of the code. The code runs and gets to the end but does not create any of the *.dat output files

Comment: You have a shebang at the top of the file to call awk but your file contains shell. Change `#!/usr/awk -f` to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as a starting point then copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the additional issues it will tell you about, and after that if you still have a question then post one that includes a minimal, complete script and concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrates just that problem.

Comment: An `awk` script should always be *outside* all Bash loops, or else you are almost certainly using `awk` extremely inefficiently. Also, your snippet makes no sense whatsoever. Please make it syntactically correct and runnable first. Also, please extend the question with example input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the files are all comma-separated and the first field (`$1`) contains the year, all you need is:

```
awk -F, '{print > FILENAME "-" $1 ".dat"}' *yyyymm.txt
```